# How jar files are executed in Ruby MRI implemetation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, jruby, mri

The [Concurrent ruby gem](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby), is supported for MRI implementation of ruby, this gem uses some JAR files, this mean Ruby(MRI) can able to execute jar files right?

is it mean Ruby(MRI) has a JVM?

P.S: I am very new to the programming world, so kindly correct me if my understandings are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The concurrent Ruby gem contains several native extensions for popular Ruby implementations. In particular, it contains one extension (written in C) for YARV and another extension (written in Java) for JRuby.

The JRuby extension is only used on JRuby, not on YARV, so YARV never needs to execute it.